# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

Wordpress permission issues. I'm getting **Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource** even after setting the below permissions. This happens while trying to access pages like `wp-admin/plugins.php`. The site itself is ok

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site
sudo find /var/www/site/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/site/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
```

After this it was still not working. I decided to give the directory full permissions `chmod -R 777`  but still it didn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was on `.htaccess` file. I restored the file to the original wordpress config and it work fine again

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Here is the wordpress htaccess config [wordpress htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/)